# Kubernetes bare-metal: Assign external IP to Node

Tags: kubernetes

I have setup a Kubernetes cluster with a few VMs. I know the external static IP of each node. Is there a way for me to manually register these external IPs to my cluster nodes?

I don't want to use Service, Ingress, MetalLB, or any cloud-specific load balancer solution.

Basically, I want to manually populate these fields for my nodes:

[image: How do I add external IPs to my nodes]

---

For context, here's what I'm trying to accomplish: I have some NodePort services which I want to expose to the internet without explicitly specifying the `externalIps` list in the service definition. I want a request from the browser to hit one of my nodes at its external IP, and inside the cluster behave as if the internal node IP was requested.

I'm assuming that if I can somehow tell my nodes what their external IP is, then this scenario will work automatically. Is this assumption correct? And if so, is there a way, `kubectl` or otherwise, for me to add external IP to my node definitions?

Else, can I achieve what I've described via a CNI plugin? Or by changing the content of `/etc/cni/net.d/10-weave.conflist`?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so to rewind, this is what the actual data structure looks like:

```
  addresses:
  - address: 10.45.0.53
    type: InternalIP
  - address: 34.127.42.172
    type: ExternalIP
```

So multiple address types are present in parallel (there's also usually hostname data set in there too). However the Kubelet only ever sets InternalIP itself, based on either `--node-ip` or the primary interface address of the system. The other values are populated by cloud controllers which you don't have. So either you need to write your own cloud controller or set up the primary IP of the node to be public (it will be noted as "internal" but IPs are IPs.

Comment: Thank you. I did a `kubectl get node cp01 -o yaml` and do see `status.addresses[]` with `InternalIp`and `Hostname` entries but no `externalIp`. Are you saying that there's no `kubectl` or other utility command that would let me mutate the node definition and add an entry to this section, without writing my own cloud controller manager or some such? I'm trying to make my services implicity accept requests sent to my external IPs (without me having to specify the IPs in each service definition). Is there a weave, or cni config change I can make to make that happen? Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: I've also edited my questions and added a bit of context to what I'm actually trying to accomplish. If you'd kindly set me on the right path, I'll do my research. I'm a networking newbie, but between setting the external IP, or fiddling with CNI Plugins or weave, I'm sure there's a way I can bring traffic in from my external IPs and make them hit the node's internal IP.

Comment: It's all up to how you are deploying your VMs and how you are deploying Kubernetes. Give the VMs public IPs and modify the kubelet command line to use them.